# How do I remotely check for Microsoft .NET Framework 4?

Tags: remote-access, .net-4.0

I've been asked to verify that all of the engineering computers in our company have Microsoft .NET Framework 4 installed.

All computers are currently turned on and are on our private network ...but all of the engineers are busy with their very demanding tasks {rolls eyes}.

Is there a way I could remotely check these PCs from my desk? I am a domain admin, so I was looking for something along the lines of a command line ping that I could do or whatever.

This would make me the hero because I'd cause no downtime to productivity!

Comment: Can't you just push .NET 4 out to all machines as part of the Windows Update procedure?

Comment: Agreed...if you've got cause for a domain you probably have cause for WSUS. For the record keeping and auditing alone its worth the time.

Comment: We have an old 2000 server. It is supposed to push stuff out, but it doesn't always happen. ...or rarely seems to work as it should for large files like "the framework". I am not involved in the push configurations; I was simply tasked with going out to all of these 200 PCs to see if the push made it to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure powershell can do that for you.  Check out the following: [PoshCode PowerShell Examples](http://poshcode.org/1628)

The official way to detect .NET versions is to look at their known location on the hard drive as per this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785

Modifying the script to support .NET 4 would be easy enough.  Just add this line:

```
V4Present = &{ if ( $res | Where-Object { $_.Major -eq 4 -and $_.Minor -eq 0 } ) { $true } }
```

Comment: I think that's it ...but first I've got to watch the MS video "Learn It Now before It's an Emergency"

Comment: I'm a PowerShell Noobie, you suggested PowerShell, so... My error is **Parameter 'ComputerName' can not be null or empty.** For PC named `ENG-CLARK`, do I simply paste that into the `$ComputerName` parameter?